# .setColor issue using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

As you can see from the below code, I am having an issue with the .setColor Just so you are aware I do have Discord.js added as a requirement but I still get the error.
Please I am very new to this so be nice :D if there is something simple.

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const Discord = new Discord.Client();

const token = require("./token");

const prefix = '!';

const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

Client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('International 1657 is online!');
});

Client.on('message', message => {
  var prefix = '!'
  var msg = message.content;

  if (msg === prefix + 'Aethelflaed') {
    message.channel.send( // inside a command, event listener, etc.
    new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Legendary Commander')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Aethelflaed', './img/LegendaryCommander/Aethelflaed.png', '#')
    .setDescription('She is one of the most powerful commanders in the game thanks to her skills and absolute strength of rarity.')
    .setThumbnail('./img/LegendaryCommander/Aethelflaed.png')
    .addFields(
         { name: 'Skills', value: 'Arrow of Iron - Thunderous Force - Synergy - Fortress of Mercia - Warrior Queen {Expertise}' },
         { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
         { name: './img/Leadership.png', value: 'Leadership |', inline: true },
         { name: './img/Peace.png', value: 'Peacekeeping |', inline: true },
       )
       .addField('./img/Support.png', 'Support', true)
       .setImage('./img/LegendaryCommander/Aethelflaed.png')
       .setTimestamp()
       .setFooter('Britain', './img/LegendaryCommander/Aethelflaed.png'));

       channel.send(exampleEmbed);
      }});

Client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'ping') {
    message.reply('pong!');
  } else if (command === 'kingdom') {
    message.reply('We are in Kingdom 1657 and Our alliance is 57kl');
  } else if (command === 'power') {
    message.reply();
  }})

Client.login(token);
```

Comment: const Discord = new Discord.Client();
                ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Discord' before initialization

This is now the error i am seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [`new MessageEmbed()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) is missing from your `message.channel.send()` method.

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

message.channel.send( // inside a command, event listener, etc.
  new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Legendary Commander')
...
...
...
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think my whole code is messed up. :(